# Expected value when longer runs have higher value

Tags: probability

Say you have a game with change $p$ of winning. The reward for winning is $+1$, losing costs you $-1$.
When you win 3 or more times in a row, the reward for winning becomes $+2$.

I am interested in what you average result $E(p)$ would be for playing a game (when you assume that game to be part of a series which all have change $p$ of winning). I also am interested in what $p$ you would need to have to have an average reward of $0$.

From simulations I that $E(\frac{1}{2}) \approx \frac{1}{8}$ and $E(0.455) \approx 0$. Is there any way to calculate the values?

Comment: What is your definition of $X$?

Comment: @Hoda I've changed the question, I think it should be more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the game, we can set up simultaneous equations:

$$
\begin{align}
E_0&=p\, (E_1+1)-q\\
E_1&=p\, (E_2+1)-q\\
E_2&=p\, (E_3+1)-q\\
E_3&=p\, (E_3+2)-q
\end{align}
$$

where $q=1-p$ and the required solution is:

$$E_0=\dfrac{{p}^{4}+2\,p-1}{1-p}$$

Hence, for $p=\frac{1}{2}$, $E_0=\frac{1}{8}$

For $E_0$ to be $0$, solve ${p}^{4}+2\,p-1=0$

The CAS maxima gives:

$
p=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\sqrt{12\,\sqrt{2\,\sqrt{43}+2\,{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\sqrt{{\left( 2\,\sqrt{43}+2\,{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) }^{\frac{2}{3}}-4}\,\left( {3}^{\frac{1}{4}}\,{\left( 2\,\sqrt{43}+2\,{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) }^{\frac{2}{3}}-4\,{3}^{\frac{1}{4}}\right) }-{3}^{\frac{5}{8}}\,{\left( {\left( 2\,\sqrt{43}+2\,{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) }^{\frac{2}{3}}-4\right) }^{\frac{3}{4}}}{2\,{3}^{\frac{7}{8}}\,{\left( 2\,\sqrt{43}+2\,{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) }^{\frac{1}{6}}\,{\left( {\left( 2\,\sqrt{43}+2\,{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) }^{\frac{2}{3}}-4\right) }^{\frac{1}{4}}}\\
p\approx 0.47462661756261
$